# Undefined font shape

Tags: fonts, xepersian

I have a `xepersian` document, e.g.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{Nazli}% http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/f/fonts-farsiweb/fonts-farsiweb_0.4.dfsg.orig.tar.xz
\begin{document}
این یک متن فارسی  است.
\textit{ادامه}
 متن فارسی...
\end{document}
```

Upon compiling I get these warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Nazli(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/Nazli(0)/m/n' instead on input line ***.
```

and the text inside `\textit{}` is not italic.
What is causing the problem? and how can I fix this?

I have used `Nazli` in LibreOffice and it has an italic shape; or isn't that the same?

Comment: I don't know Farsi, but is there a concept of `italic` characters in that language/glyphs at all?

Comment: It's possible that LibreOffice fakes italic by slanting the letters.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Yes. I should have mentioned with [FreeFarsi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/) I don't have this problem.

Comment: @egreg It must do. There is no italic in the package so far as I can tell.

Comment: @cfr, Is there a way for us to do the same here?

Comment: Yes, as @egreg shows. However, the fact that it can be done does not mean that it ought to be done. Faked italics, like faked small-caps, are Evil. Font designers tend to feel quite strongly on this point in my (admittedly limited) experience. Italics are not slanted versions of upright fonts. Even oblique is not merely a slanted version of upright. At least, not for Latin scripts. For all I know, this might be perfectly fine in Arabic or Persian. Though I have my doubts.

Comment: Italics in Arabic script are just slanted (faked) versions. Just remembering, italics make no sense in Fraktur either. There are other ways to emphasize words, though. I'd rather underline, use bold or even a different font/style for Arabic script (that's what "italics" were in the beginning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word processors like LibreOffice usually fake missing italic shape by geometrically slanting the glyphs. You can obtain the same result with XeLaTeX using the `FakeSlant` option to `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont[
  Script=Arabic,
  ItalicFont=Nazli,
  ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=-0.5},
]{Nazli}
\begin{document}
این یک متن فارسی  است.
\textit{ادامه}
 متن فارسی...
\end{document}
```

Probably 0.5 is exaggerated, but I used it for making the slanting more visible. The value should be negative in order to slant to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-fonts/fonts-farsiweb.git/tree/), the fonts contained in the package are four:

```
homa.ttf    
nazli.ttf   
nazlib.ttf  
titr.ttf
```

None of these appears to be a candidate for an italic version of Nazli. `nazli.ttf` is the regular, upright Nazli. `nazlib.ttf` provides Nazli Bold.

`homa.ttf` and `titr.ttf` are distinct fonts: Homa and Titr. These are not directly related to Nazli - they are just released by upstream as part of the same collection of fonts, and included in Debian's package because these, together with Nazli, are suitably licensed.

For more information about the Debian package see [README.Debian](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-fonts/fonts-farsiweb.git/tree/debian/README.Debian).

Comment: `homa.ttf` and `titr.ttf`aren't really related to `Nazli`. They are just in the same package.

Comment: @Furihr Quite. That is why I said they are 'distinct fonts'. That is, of course, it depends on how you individuate fonts. But I hoped the contrast between those and Nazli/Nazli Bold would be clear enough. Can you suggest how I might clarify it further? Maybe I should just say 'and are not related to Nazli'?

Comment: @Furihr I've clarified a bit. Is that better?